# Why does the file history tree no longer display?

Tags: tortoisehg

When I choose to view a file's Revision History using TortoiseHg, it no longer displays the file's history in a tree view.

Here's an example screenshot from a quick test:

[image]

I assume that I unintentionally hit some hot key that hid the tree, but I don't know what that might be - nor have I been able to find any information online about it.

I uninstalled the version I had, and installed the current version (4.9), but still have the same behavior.

A little help?  The tree view of repo and file history is the only reason I use TortoiseHg.

Comment: How strange. I tried and could not find a way to reproduce your screenshot. If you don't get a good answer here, consider posting at https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out.

You can move the divider between the tree area and commit are to grow or shrink however you wish.  You can move that divider so far up that the tree area is no longer visible, at all.  It appears I accidentally did this, and from that point, the window keeps opening in that way, using the last layout as its default.

It looked like it was just gone without a trace.